# Can the category of chain complexes be realized as a functor category?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

As the title says, is there some sort of category $\mathsf{C}$ which can be thought of as the "walking chain complex", so that the category of chain complexes in some other category $\mathsf{A}$ can be realized as $\mathsf{A}^\mathsf{C}$ (or perhaps some subcategory thereof)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the case of homological complexes bounded below by zero, **C** would be the preadditive category where

- Objects are natural numbers
- $\hom(n+1, n) = \mathbb{Z}$ (call the generator $\partial$)
- $\hom(n, n) = \mathbb{Z}$ (the generator is $1_n$)
- All other homsets are zero

In other words, it's the preadditive category presented by

- Objects are natural numbers
- One generating arrow $\partial : n+ 1 \to n$ for each $n$
- All relations $\partial \circ \partial = 0$

Since an abelian group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to H$ is the same thing as an element of $H$, an *additive* functor $F : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{A}$ is the same thing as:

- A choice $F_n$ of object of **A** for each natural number $n$
- A choice of morphism $\partial : F_{n+1} \to F_n$ for each natural number $n$
- Such that $\partial \circ \partial = 0$

In other words, an additive functor $F : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{A}$ is the same thing as a chain complex with terms in $\mathbf{A}$. On the other hand, a natural transformation between functors $F,G : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{A}$ is the same thing as a chain map between complexes $f:F\to G$. Symbolically, $\operatorname{Fun}_{\text{add}}(\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A})\cong\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$.

---

IIRC, an amusing alternative way to construct **C** is the following procedure:

- Start with the opposite simplex category $\Delta^\circ$
- Linearize it (i.e. replace the homsets with the free abelian homgroups) to geta preadditive category $\mathbb{Z}\Delta^\circ$
- Split all idempotents

The additive category generated by this is equivalent to the additive category generated by **C**. (if you want **C** exactly, you can extract it as a full subcategory)

This is a sort of 'universal' form of the Dold-Kan correspondence, showing the walking simplicial abelian group is, in an appropriate sense, equivalent to the walking chain complex.

Comment: That's really awesome! By "split all idempotents" do you mean take the [Karoubi envelope](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubi+envelope)?

Comment: To get the category of all chain complexes (not just bounded below), extend the category C to have objects given by all integers.

Comment: Here is another take on the isomorphism $\operatorname{Fun}_{\text{add}}(\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A})\cong\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$: Denote $\mathbf{PADD}$ to the category whose objects are the locally small preadditive categories and whose morphisms are the additive functors between them. Then $\mathbf{A}\mapsto\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$ defines the action on objects of an endofunctor of $\mathbf{PADD}$. This functor is representable by $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: An interesting corollary of $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathbf{C},\mathbf{A})\cong\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$ is that it allows to compute a (co)limit in $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})$ by taking the term-wise (co)limit in $\mathbf{A}$ (provided that all the latter (co)limits exist), as [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4545784/394668) says. (Note that this doesn't mean that the $n$ᵗʰ evaluation functor $\operatorname{Ch}(\mathbf{A})\to\mathbf{A},\ A^\bullet\mapsto A^n$ preserves limits. I don't know

Comment: right now a specific counterexample, but maybe one could obtain one from the ideas given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2744570/394668).)