# Monomorphisms and epimorphisms in the category of chain complexes

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, monomorphisms, epimorphisms

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be an abelian category and $\mathsf{Comp(C)}$ its category of chain complexes. Suppose that $f\colon (C,d)\to (C',d')$ is a monomorphism in $\mathsf{Comp(C)}$. I want to prove that each $f_n\colon C_n\to C'_n$ is a monomorphism in $\mathsf{C}$. Similarly, if $f$ is an epimorphism, I want to prove that each $f_n$ is an epimorphism (I'm not sure it can be proven by duality from assuming the monomorphism case, in particular, I don't think $\mathsf{Comp(C^{op})} = \mathsf{Comp(C)^{op}}$).

If $g,h\colon X\rightrightarrows C_n$ such that $f_n\circ g = f_n\circ h$, to show that $g = h$, we need to construct a complex $(C'',d'')$ and a morphisms $g',h'\colon (C'',d'') \rightrightarrows (C,d)$ such that $g'_n = g, h'_n = h$ and $g'\circ f = h'\circ f$. But I can't guees what $(C'',d'')$ and $g',h'$ should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The category of chain complexes is isomorphic to a full subcategory of the category of functors $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathsf{C}$ (where $\Bbb Z$ is zeen as a thin category), closed under limits and colimits. In fact it is even isomorphic to a category of enriched functors (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2139250/can-the-category-of-chain-complexes-be-realized-as-a-functor-category)) into $\mathsf{C}$.

So all limits and colimits of chain complexes are constructed "pointwise", which implies that mono/epi-morphisms are pointwise mono/epimorphisms, and also that the category is abelian.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you know that your category of complexes is abelian.

Given a chain map $f_*\colon (C_*, d)\to (C_*', d')$, we may consider the complex $(K_*, \delta)$, where $K_n\ker(f_n)$ and $\delta_n$ is the restriction of $d_n$ to $K_n$. To see this, it suffices to show that if $f_n(x)=0$, then $d_n(x)\in\ker(f_{n-1})$, but this follows from the fact that $f_*$ is a chain map: $d'_n\circ f_n = f_{n-1}\circ d_n$. Thus, we have the morphisms $\delta_n\colon K_n\to K_{n-1}$, and they satisfy $\delta_{n-1}\circ\delta_n$. You can then show that $(K_*, \delta_*)$ is a kernel of $f_*$. Then, like in any abelian category, $f_*$ is a monomorphism if and only if its kernel is trivial. Note that triviality does not mean contractibility, but that $K_n=0$ for each $n$. Thus, $f_*$ is a monomorphism if and only if $K_n=0$ for each $n$, but this is equivalent to $f_n$ being a monomorphism.

For epimorphisms, the idea is similar. Here, however, we construct a complex using cokernels. Again, the fact that $f_*$ is a chain map induces a differential between the consequent cokernels: $d'_n(\text{im}(f_n))\subseteq \text{im}(f_{n-1}\circ d_n)\subseteq\text{im}(f_{n-1})$. Now $f_*$ is an epimorphism if and only if the cokernel complex (which is a cokernel of $f_*$!) is trivial, but then the cokernels of all $f_n$ are trivial, and so each $f_n$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: Well, how do you prove that the category of complexes is abelian if you don't know what its monomorphisms and epimorphisms are? One of the axioms of the abelian category says that every monomorphism is a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel. Seems like a circular argument.

Comment: Good point. You don't actually need abelianness. You can show that those give you kernels and cokernels of chain maps, and that follows easily. Suppose $g_*\colon C''_*\to C_*$ is a chain map such that $f_*\circ g_*=0$. Then $f_n\circ g_n=0$ for each $n$, so you can factor $g_n$ through the kernel of $f_n$ and so on.